# My dad used my tea brewer with coffee and now the plastic makes my tea taste like coffee. Bleach?

Tags: coffee, tea

How can I get the coffee taste out of the plastic in my tea brewer. Its all plastic. Will bleach ruin it?

Comment: Can you please clarify what type of tea maker, type of plastic piece you're referring to, etc. Different plastics will react with chemicals in a variety of ways especially depending on the temperature at which they are interacting. The more details you can share the better.

Comment: I read the title as "...my tea tastes like coffee.  blecch!"  As in yuck.  I agree, that is a terrible thing to do to tea.  :)

Comment: If the plastic is porous enough to absorb the taste of coffee, it will be porous enough to absorb the taste of bleach as well.

Answer (score 14):

Plain white vinegar is the normal way to remove coffee tastes and stains. Hot vinegar works better